# New coworkers don't have to clock out and get paid more as a result

Tags: management, salary, retail

I work in retail. We are scheduled for 8 hour shifts. The pay system is directly tied to when we clock in and out: so if we clock in 1 minute late we get paid 1 minute less, and if we clock out 1 minute late, we get paid 1 minute more. For the closing shift we/I have been instructed to finish the closing duties as quickly as possible and clock out as soon as they are done. This is probably so the company can save a bit of money. Some of the closing duties are very subjective and not clearly defined, for example "tidy the place up". So it's easy for someone to decide to leave early.

To my understanding, there's a problem with on-boarding the new employees in the system. So the new employees don't clock in and out and always get paid the full 8 hours regardless if they leave early or start late. In terms of morale, I find this very unfair. Should I say anything about it, or try to swallow it?

Comment: So if they stay late, there is no evidence so they don’t get paid any extra.

Comment: @SolarMike yes, and for that reason they never stay late and always leave early

Comment: @JoeStrazzere And how would the manager know if the OP doesn't tell him? OP should tell the manager to save them money and to make himself feel better, this kills two birds with one stone.

Comment: Are they, in fact, working a good deal less than 8 hour days and are claiming the 8 hour pay, or are they simply not doing closing time jobs because they know staying late won't positively impact their pay?

And, if it's a problem with on-boarding them into the pay system, it sounds like assuming 8 hours is a "make due" measure until that get fixed. Is this correct?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just to summarise your concern:

The new employees are assumed to work 8 hours.

Because this isn’t tracked, they avoid doing some of the closing duties eg tidying the place up, leave early, and still get paid for 8 hours.

You are upset because this is unfair. And want to know if you should do something about it.

IMO, what you should do is this;

**If** their actions are affecting your work:

You have to stay later to finish the jobs they left.

You can’t do everything you’re supposed to in the morning because there’s work left over from the previous evening.

Store standards/KPIs are slipping. Or perceived to be slipping. Or other problems are being caused.

**Then** you bring it to management. Focusing on the specific issue (see above) and the specific cause (some people not completing all the work before leaving in the evening). And that’s it.

You don’t talk about *why* you think people are leaving early. Just stick to facts. “X is happening, which is causing Y issues”. And then you let management deal with it however they want to.

If it’s not affecting your work then you should just leave it alone. It’s not your job to manage people. And there’s plenty of ways it could turn out negatively for you if you try to get involved.

Comment: "If their actions are affecting your work" Here is the thing: It is not possible to accurately predict if things will get busier after someone leaves. On several occasions there's been one or two instances where things went really badly because something came up that I needed a second person. We are on the same team so them not being there always affects me in the sense they never to completely 0. (To be clear I'm not trying to argue with you, more so elaborate)

Comment: Right, so that’s exactly when you bring it to your manager. “Hey, we had a problem today with [X] because I was the only person left on closing when it happened”. Hopefully, they then ask “why were you the only person left on closing?”. At which point you just say that the other person left at [time].

Comment: Is it policy that you have to have 2 people on closing?

Answer (score 6):

Is your focus on what other people are getting away with making you happier or unhappier? Life is going to be full of situations that are unfair. Before you get involved in complaining about what other people are doing, it's best to ask yourself "What do I hope to accomplish by complaining?"

Making sure the company is only paying someone for the hours they worked isn't your job, and you don't have the information or authority to do that properly. If the work isn't being done because someone is leaving early or starting late, then discuss that with your manager or someone who has the authority to fix the problem. Complaining to your manager about fairness makes you look immature. Focus on what you want to happen (I don't want to have to do the work of two people at closing because someone left early, I don't want to have to clean up in the morning because other people didn't do their job).

Whether someone did or didn't get paid for the hours they did or didn't work has no direct effect on your ability to do your job properly. The fact that the work isn't getting done is what you need to go to your manager about. Explain the situation without pointing fingers or complaining about unfairness, answer any questions truthfully, and let your manager solve the problem.

Comment: I don't see how being concerned with fairness in the workplace is silly/immature

Answer (score 5):

> To my understanding, there's a problem with on-boarding the new employees in the system.

This part seems overlooked in the other answers. If I'm understanding you correctly, you are implying an issue with their onboarding process - either technical or bureaucratic - which currently prevents the new people from clocking in and out. This answer is based on that premise, if it's not true please see the other answers. The same if they are actually not doing their jobs - that has been covered.

First of all, if they have been employed very recently, give it some time, this is obviously a temporary situation that management should be interested in resolving ASAP. I'd say wait until a week, maybe two, have passed.

What you *can* do after that time has passed highly depends on your relationship with your superiors.

If there *is* someone up the chain who you know well and trust I would mention this in an unofficial discussion. Let them know this, however temporary, unfairness is affecting team morale. Be ready to hear that there is nothing they can do to fix this situation.

If there is no one up the chain you trust enough to talk about this issue, I do not think you can do anything aside from sending an anonymous complaint (preferably from a burner email or something like that).

Lastly, as this is temporary - you could just power through. Grit your teeth, and just wait for their clocking issues to be resolved.

On a personal note, I believe the fair thing in this situation would be to either log the newbies' time in a different way (is there a supervisor around during closing? they could note it down) or pay the whole closing shift the full eight hours until this is resolved.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the technical issues around getting people on the clocking system. I work in manufacturing, so, pretty large amounts of people to be managed, overseas service centers processing HR and IT stuff. It took between 3-5 days to have the newbies able to clock in and out, and showing up on the time control system. During those days they got the full day of pay because nobody wanted the hassle of cross-checking building security logs to see when exactly they came in or left

Comment: I agree with this "First of all, if they have been employed very recently, give it some time," though it has been a month. How long is reasonable?

Comment: @casablancaeggplant if it's been a month, IMO it's past reasonable already.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience this stack isn't a great place to ask for any management advise. Most of the participants here are predominantly workers, and most of the answers will be to "*think from the workers perspective*" or something similar and often will not even consider current practices or the reality of the world as it is (sometimes unfair, and even unethical).

That is why your questions are being downvoted, and many are questioning your motive instead.

As it is, people don't like the idea that some co-workers are paid more than others for the same job (varying pay-scale for a role), but have accepted it because they believe the management that someone is more valuable (perhaps because of his / her experience or better educational qualification) than them, and thus deserves the better pay.

Thus, your question is quite fair either as a worker or as a manager - obviously if a work process or policy is not fair and creating a disparity in both the amount of work expected and the pay you receive, it will create resentment in the workforce and thus affect the morale in the workplace.

The obvious question to be asked here is, if everyone is being paid hourly, then why are the newbies exempted from logging in and logging out? And why have the management only exempted the newbies, and not everyone?

If you have the answer to these questions, you can approach the higher-ups more confidently.

For example, I can think of two reasons (both of which maybe wrong):

1. The pandemic may have made it more difficult to find workers, and thus management is forced to relax the rules to attract workers.
2. The management may be looking to exploit the workers as the pandemic has affected everyone economically, and the "no logging" exemptions allows them to work the newbies for longer hours. But somehow, management has failed to communicate this to the mid-level managers and thus the newbies have escaped this.

As you can see, depending on either one or two, management's response to your question will vary largely. If it is 1, they are trying to take advantage of the old employees, and will not be interested in addressing your complaint. If it is 2, they are interested in taking advantage of the newbies, and once you report the matter to them, they will.

If you are the manager, I pity you, because both are dicey situations you don't want to be in as you will face the ire of some part of the workforce. If you are an older employee, you may either be asked to suck it, or make the newbie employees work harder.

(Management is only interested in what benefits them. So address everything that way. Your bosses look to you to make thier jobs easier. Someone who complains about everything without fully understanding the issue. and without a practical solution, will be treated as a nuisance to them. The point is, before approaching management with a complaint, always try to see things from their perspective and find out why something is the way it, or it may backfire on you. )

Then file a complaint as [@kaz summarized](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/177176/124245) in his good answer.